# Get parameters dynamically from URL in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

Assume the URL is

```
...&q0=aaa&q1=bbb&q2=ccc&q4=ddd...
```

What I am doing in the JSP file is:

```
var qs = [];
qs.push("${q0}");
qs.push("${q1}");
qs.push("${q2}");
qs.push("${q3}");
```

I'd like to access q0...q4 dynamically; something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var temp = "q" + i;    
    qs.push("${temp}")
}
```

But I don't know to make it work. Searched the forum but couldn't find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is supported by [a majority of browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams)

```
const url = new URL('https://example.com?q0=aaa&q1=bbb&q2=ccc&q4=ddd')
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1))
params.get('q0') // expect "aaa"
params.get('q1') // expect "bbb"
params.get('q2') // expect "ccc"
params.get('q5') // expect null because q5 doesn't exist
```

Look at the documentation for more methods.

Comment: Thanks. My mind was stuck in how to work it out using EL and forgot I can get the data from URL directly.